# How to make an event work for an array with angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

i'm a beginner in Angular and i don't know how to express what I want, but I have this `div` and I want to change its size when the `sM` array is between 4 and 6 for example, but that only changes the first one. I do not know why.

this my div

```
  <div class="col-4" id="product" *ngFor="let sm of sM" [ngClass]="ChangeHeigth()">
    <img class="img2" src="assets/images/xx/xxx.svg" alt="">
    <img class="img1" src="assets/images/xx/xxx.svg" alt="">
    <h5>{{sm.name}}</h5>
    <p>{{sm.res}}</p>
    <button routerLink="/product_detail"><span>+ Info</span></button>
  </div>
```

and this my event

```
  ChangeHeigth() {
    if (this.sM.length > 3 && this.sM.length < 7) {
      document.getElementById('product').style.height = '55%';
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method getElementById gives you the first element of the DOM with given id. There's a better way of doing this without using the `document` object.

On the div, try changing `[ngClass]` for `[ngStyle]`

and on your ChangeHeight method, try changing the way you change the style by doing this:

```
ChangeHeigth() {
    if (this.sM.length > 3 && this.sM.length < 7) {
      return {'height': '55%'};
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all using functions in templates is discouraged in Angular, use Pipes instead. [Here](https://medium.com/showpad-engineering/why-you-should-never-use-function-calls-in-angular-template-expressions-e1a50f9c0496) is a good read.

In your case you can set the current index to a variable and use that to toggle the class.

E.g. something like the following:

```css
.h-55 {
  height:55%;
}
```

In template

```html
<div class="col-4" id="product" *ngFor="let sm of sM; index as currentIndex" [class.h-55]="currentIndex > 3 && currentIndex < 7">
    <img class="img2" src="assets/images/xx/xxx.svg" alt="">
    <img class="img1" src="assets/images/xx/xxx.svg" alt="">
    <h5>{{sm.name}}</h5>
    <p>{{sm.res}}</p>
    <button routerLink="/product_detail"><span>+ Info</span></button>
</div>
```

Comment: This works but if i were to change the style several times i would have to write `[class.xx]` several times.

Comment: @JoãoFreitas Well in that case you are indeed better off using `[ngStyle]` and let your function / pipe return the style object.